# Apollo Client useLazyQuery fetchMore not updating loading or called

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client

I am using the `useLazyQuery` hook for Apollo Client(3.6.2)

```
  const [ getOSO, { loading: loadingOSO, fetchMore: fetchMoreOSO, networkStatus: networkStatusOSO, called: calledOSO } ] = useLazyQuery(SALES_ORDERS, {
    options: {
      notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
      nextFetchPolicy: 'cache-first',
    },
  })
```

and in a `useEffect` hook:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(networkStatusOSO)
    console.log(loadingOSO)
    console.log(calledOSO)
    setTableLoading(
      loadingOSO ||
      calledOSO ||
      networkStatusOSO === NetworkStatus.fetchMore ||
      networkStatusOSO === NetworkStatus.refetch
    )
  }, [ loadingOSO, networkStatusOSO, calledOSO ])
```

This is the call to `fetchMore`:

```
        fetchMoreOSO( { 
          variables: { ...newPageCursor },
       }, updateQuery )
        .then((results) => {
          const fetchedOrders = results.data.orders.edges.map(item => item.node)
          setOrders( fetchedOrders )
          setPageInfo( results.data.orders.pageInfo )
        })
```

I only see the `useEffect` updated on the initial query not on any of the `fetchMore` calls. All documentation that I've found says that just setting `notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true` should be it but that's not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here using Apollo and react stack. Seems like other users are facing this as well in their [github issue](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues?q=is%3Aissue+uselazyquery+loading+is%3Aopen).

A workaround is to setState in the fetchMore updateQuery option.

Example

```
const [loadingMore, setLoadingMore] = useState(false);


const loadMoreCustom = () => {
  setLoadingMore(true)
  fetchMore({
    variables:{//yourvariables}
    updateQuery: (prev, {more}) => {
      ...
      setLoadingMore(false)
    }
  })
}
```